# jquery-Knob library

Tags: jquery

Добрый день всем.Пытаюсь подключить библиотеку jquery-knob, устанавливал через npm install jquery-knob, в package-json она есть`"jquery-knob": "^1.2.11",` но все равно выдает ошибку такую `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).knob is not a function`

Comment: подозреваю, что вы в проект ее не импортировали

Comment: npm install делал, или нужно через cdn подключить?

Comment: `npm install` только скачивает скрипты в папку `node_modules`

Comment: так я делал npm install jquery-knob, может подскажете как ее дальше установить то?

Comment: Так-же, как и jquery, я не знаю организации вашего приложения, вариантов может быть куча, надо чтобы библиотека оказалась на странице